# Tamil input not working in emacs after version 25

Tags: input-method

I have been using emacs for almost 7 years now. Started with emacs 23. I have used to read and write tamil language text inside emacs with both scim-input and ibus under gnome without any additional config inside emacs. But after switching to emacs 25 the system input is not working and even inside if I select tamil-itrans input methods, I cannot type in tamil text.

Even tamil script rendering has been degraded. What can I do to rectify this??

[image: screenshot of zim and emacs showing tamil text]

Comment: Are you using one of the m17n layouts? I'm using emacs 27 on gnome. No issues with Tamil text rendering. Typing also works out of the box for prebuilt Tamil input methods on ibus, named *Tamil (Inscript)*, *Tamil (Tamilnet '99)*, *Tamil (Srilanka, Tamilnet '99)*, etc. (However, they are wrong keyboard layouts, not really Tamil-99). I'm unable to type with *m17n* layouts on emacs. Do non m17n Tamil layouts work for you?

Comment: Add this extra stuff to your .emacs, `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Baamini"))` & you will be able to type all tamil keys inside emacs. But, your minibuffer will also be using tamil font, thus you cannot do read any ctrl-keys / commands inputs

Answer (score 0):

[`tamil-phonetic`](https://github.com/rnchzn/tamil-phonetic) is an `Emacs Lisp` library which provides phonetic input natively.  See [Tamil Phonetic Input Method in Emacs / Emacs-இல் தமிழ் ஃபொனெடிக் முறையில் type செய்வது எப்படி?](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2022/03/07/tamil-phonetic-input-method-in-emacs-emacs-%e0%ae%87%e0%ae%b2%e0%af%8d-%e0%ae%a4%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%bf%e0%ae%b4%e0%af%8d-%e0%ae%83%e0%ae%aa%e0%af%8a%e0%ae%a9%e0%af%86%e0%ae%9f%e0%ae%bf%e0%ae%95%e0%af%8d/) for more information.